# Xcode 6 just displays the text "Some" as only value for my Swift class objects

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, lldb

I'm trying to debug why a UIButton isn't displaying in a view displayed by a Keyboard extension written in Swift. When it's displayed in the LLDB debugger (Xcode 6.0.1) as

```
dismissButton = (UIButton!) Some
```

I tried to examine it's contacts using the little hierarchal arrow in front of the variable, but nothing displays when I toggle it.

I try to print it out with PO and get

```
<UIButton: 0x7fa673e0c6f0; frame = (27 14; 183 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa673e0b680>>
```

Which seems incomplete at best (where is hidden?)

Is there any way to directly examine the properties of a Swift class object in LLDB? I can't use the View Hierarchy debugger since "Capture View Hierarchy" is never enabled for this project, no matter which simulator I try (iOS 8 from 4s up to 6).

Edit: As per Enrico's suggestion

```
(lldb) frame var -d run -- self.dismissButton
(UIButton!) self.dismissButton = Some {}
```

I googled but haven't found any documentations on what "Some" means in the debugger context. Wondering if I have some configuration problem with the project. The container App is Swift as well, but is just a template app, went entirely with defaults as produced by Xcode 6.0.1.

Edit2: Enrico, just typing 'frame var' produces verbose output with the following in it

```
  dismissButton = Some {
    Some = 0x00007fb90261f2e0 {
      UIKit.UIControl = {
        UIKit.UIView = {
          UIKit.UIResponder = {
            ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It's more interesting, glad to find that Some actually means something (wasn't sure if it was a special case version of nil), but still need a way to dig into the objects more.

Comment: The "incomplete" po output is not an LLDB problem (po is driven by the frameworks, not by us)

Comment: As for the "Some", I am surprised it didn't show you a pointer value if you expand open. Can you try (lldb) frame var -d run -- dismissButton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your UIButton is a Swift optional (notice the bang sign at the end of the name), its type is not UIButton, it's Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional

This is an enum with two cases

```
enum IOU<T> {
  case Some(T)
  case None
}
```

The Some you're seeing is just that: the case of the enum that corresponds to "this optional contains a UIButton"

Unfortunately, I don't think 6.0.1 will get you much farther than you already have gotten. po-ing works because it knows to unwrap on your behalf.